# Xamarin iOS: actool returning code 72 (Visual Studio 2022 Preview 17.3.0)

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, visual-studio-2022, xcode13.3.1

After upgrading Xcode from 13.1 to 13.3.1 (including command line tools) on my Mac Mini build machine, I'm getting this:

```
2>  Ausführung des Tools "/usr/bin/xcrun" abgeschlossen (Exitcode = 72).
2>          
2>  2022-05-16 15:37:26.832 xcodebuild[30231:9756916] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2>  2022-05-16 15:37:26.833 xcodebuild[30231:9756916] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2>  xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk" cannot be located.
2>  xcrun: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find actool 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 16384: (null) (errno=No such file or directory)
2>  xcrun: error: unable to find utility "actool", not a developer tool or in PATH
2>  
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(842,3): error : /usr/bin/xcrun mit Code 72 beendet
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(842,3): error :         
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(842,3): error : 2022-05-16 15:37:26.832 xcodebuild[30231:9756916] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(842,3): error : 2022-05-16 15:37:26.833 xcodebuild[30231:9756916] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(842,3): error : xcodebuild: error: SDK "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk" cannot be located.
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(842,3): error : xcrun: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find actool 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 16384: (null) (errno=No such file or directory)
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(842,3): error : xcrun: error: unable to find utility "actool", not a developer tool or in PATH
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(842,3): error : 
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(842,3): error : actool mit Code 72 beendet
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(842,3): error :         
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets(842,3): error : Fehler beim Laden der actool-Protokolldatei "obj/iPhoneSimulator/Debug/actool/asset-manifest.plist": Failed to parse PList data type: 
2>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\MSBuild\Xamarin
```

Note that due to the puny 128GB internal drive, I have symlinked /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents to an external Thunderbolt drive. This worked well before.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you "Open" Xcode after updating? Sometimes it likes to install additional tools, but it only prompts you when you open it. If that doesn't work, you may need to make sure the location of tools is set correctly: https://github.com/distriqt/AIR-ImageScripts/issues/1#issuecomment-779171135.

Comment: Please try to Remove CommandLineTools,Reinstall it and then select it,please refer to https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/703233 for more details.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Reinstalling just the command line tool didn't work. Xcode wanted to install other packages but pressing the install button didn't trigger any action. Only the Quit button worked. I ended up Reinstalling the whole Xcode on the system drive again after removing some stuff (which lead to other problems).